# Is Socket bundled with Pry?

Tags: ruby, sockets, irb, pry

I'm learning socket in Ruby. I tried `require 'socket'` in a Pry session only to get `false`. After much trouble, I decided to use `irb` but things worked fine.

Later, I ran `TCPServer.new('localhost', 2000)` in a pry session without requiring `socket` and it worked!

I'm curious as to why it's so. Is it that `socket` is already part of pry? I checked Pry source code but could not figure it out.

Pry version 0.10.3 on Ruby 2.3.0

Comment: No, `socket` isn’t loaded by default when you start Pry. Do you have a `.pryrc` file that is loading it perhaps?

Comment: At the time it happened, I didn't have a `.pryrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `socket` is loaded in Pry when it starts. Whereas irb does not load it initially. You can always tells if a file has already been loaded because `require` will return `false`, as opposed to a `LoadError`.

```
2.3.1 :001 > require 'socket' # not yet loaded
# => true 
2.3.1 :002 > require 'socket' # already loaded
# => false 
2.3.1 :003 > require 'not_a_file' # error because it does not exist
# LoadError: cannot load such file -- not_a_file
```

Comment: Where do you get that Pry loads `socket` automatically? It doesn’t for me, and the only mentions in the source for “socket” appear to be a comment and a changelog entry.

Comment: @matt true the Github repository does not directly `require 'socket'` but it does load other Gems, which is likely the culprit. What version of Pry do you have? `pry -v`

Comment: `0.10.3`, the current latest. I don’t have any plugins though, maybe you and mokayode both have a plugin that requires `socket`? What do you get from `pry --plugins`

Comment: @matt nope, `Installed Plugins: --`. And I don't have a `.pryrc` file.

Comment: In the Pry Github repo I do see a couple of mentions of [`require 'net/http'`](https://github.com/pry/pry/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=net), which has a [`require 'net/protocol'`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb#L23), which has [`require 'socket'`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/protocol.rb#L22).